# React file viewer with pdf file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm using React-file-viewer , and it works, except for PDF file ! 
This is my code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FileViewer from 'react-file-viewer'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <FileViewer fileType="pdf"
                  filePath="a.pdf" />
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

And I have this result :

[image]

[image]

I've pdfjs-dist on my dependencies. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: the code is not built properly, have to tried converting jsx to js using babel compiler?

Comment: what do you use to bootstrap your react project?

Comment: I've just created a simple react project with command "create-react-app my-app", and integrate react file viewer

Answer (score 0):

**use require at top like as follows.**
make sure, file mustnot be outside of src folder.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FileViewer from 'react-file-viewer'
const filePath = require(filepath/filename.pdf);

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <FileViewer fileType="pdf"
                  filePath={filePath} />
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileViewer.open(filepath) .then(() =>{ 
console.log('success');
})
        .catch(error =>{ 
          console.log(error);
}
```

Its working for pdf,video,audio and image file

Is this file viewer works for .docx file or .xls file? Could you please explain how to achieve this.

Comment: This seems to be part answer part question. Please separate those two. Keep the answering part here, add some explanation on how it works. Delete the question part here and create a new actual question by using the "Ask Question" button on the top right of this page.